# PgBouncer don't start the minimum connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgbouncer

I have set in pgBouncer this limits

> max_client_conn = 2000
>
> default_pool_size = 40

When i execute this SQL in phpPgAdmin, only 2 or 4 connections appears:

```
SELECT datname, usename, pid, query, query_start
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity
                WHERE datname='example'
                ORDER BY usename, pid
```

This is normal or pgBouncer don't loaded the .ini when started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of connections in `pg_stat_activity` depends on the actual load. Also it depend more on [pool_mode](https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html) - if you have `pool_mode = session`, you will see more sessions just because the are released less often and slower.

Regarding your options, check out the [docs](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html) (allowed - is a key word):

> ## default_pool_size
>
> How many server connections to **allow** per user/database pair. Can be overridden in the per-database
> configuration.
>
> Default: 20

and

> ## max_client_conn
>
> Maximum number of client connections **allowed**. When increased then the file descriptor limits should also be increased.
> Note that actual number of file descriptors used is more than
> max_client_conn.

Emphasis mine.